# Redirecionamento de página e dados com Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

#### Cenário teste

Tenho uma página de `login.php`, que verifica o usuário e senha com ajax, enviando os dados via post para o arquivo `valida.php`.

O `valida.php`, quando a autenticação der certo, deveria redirecionar para outra página, levando os dados em `$_POST`. Mas se usar um `header` por exemplo, ele retorna `error` ao invés de `success`.

---

#### Arquivos

`login.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php require_once 'html\head.php' ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function login(){
            var myData = $("#login").serialize();
            arquivo = "valida.php";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                data: myData,
                url: arquivo,
                success:function(response){
                    //alert(response);
                    $('#ret').html(response).show();
                },
                error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="assets/img/truck.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            Teste
        </a>
        <form id="login" class="form-inline">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Usuário" aria-label="User">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="Senha" aria-label="Pass">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-warning my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" onclick="login();">Entrar</button>
        </form>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="ret"></div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

`valida.php`

```
set_time_limit(10);

$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'user');
$pswd = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'pswd');

if (isset($user) && isset($pswd)) {
    
    if ($user == 'rbz' && $pswd == 123) {

        header('location: ok.php');
        
    } else {

        echo '<br><div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>Atenção!</strong> Usuário ou senha incorretos.
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div><br>';
    }

} else {

    echo "preencha os 2 campos";
}
```

---

- Como poderia redirecionar a página, mantendo os dados em `$_POST`?

Comment: Porque não envia por `$_SESSION[]` ?

Comment: Há 2 casos. Eu não tenho uma session, mas poderia sim já iniciar no `valida.php` e redirecionar (ainda teria o problema do redirecionamento (faço no retorno de `success`!? seria o ideal!?), e tem a opção de não abrir a session no `valida.php`, então manteria a dúvida da pergunta.

Comment: Não há como redirecionar post, então o que pretende não há como fazer. Por que precisa que esses dados sejam reenviados como post?

Comment: Montei seu ambiente aqui para fazer alguns testes, me deparei com 2 coisas, mantendo a resposta 302, o ajax funciona corretamente porem fazendo o retorno 200 o ajax nem chega a da erro. nem nada no console.

Answer (score 1):

Da maneira como está fazendo a função `header()`não será interpretada e o redirecionamento não ocorrerá como resposta a uma requisição assícrona.

Isso porque os cabeçalhos de resposta já foram enviados antes do PHP interpretar a função `header()`.

Para contornar a situação, você pode verificar se existe alguma saída enviada ao navegador quando sua função `header()` é invocada.

Uma forma de fazer isso é utilizando a função `headers_sent()`.

Após validar o login e a senha, você poderia fazer algo como:

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('Location: ok.php');
    exit;
}else{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="ok.php";</script>';
    exit;
}
```

Basicamente o script verificará se algum cabeçalho já foi enviado como resposta. Se nenhum foi enviado, o PHP tentará o redirecionamento com `header()` caso contrário, irá gerar uma mensagem como esta:

**"Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"**

Porque alguns cabeçalhos já foram enviados.

Mas para contornar este problema, o `else` será executado e o PHP tentará o redirecionamento com o **Javascript**.

No entanto, essa ainda não seria a melhor forma de redirecionar a resposta da sua requisição.

Você pode permitir que o arquivo `valida.php` envie somente uma resposta boleana informando se as credenciais de acesso são válidas ou não. Ou, você pode enviar um array com as informações do usuário em caso de autenticação positiva e retornar um array vazio em caso de autenticação negativa.

E com isto, utilizar o Javascript / jQuery para realizar o redirecionamento.

Ou até mesmo realizar outras ações que não sejam especificamente o redirecionamento.

As vantagens de fazer isto com Javascript é a liberdade que isso te garantirá.

Por outro lado, como desvantagem, é o fato de que o Javascript pode ser desabilitado no navegador e isto fará com que a autenticação de login não funcione. Contudo, você pode informar que é necessário manter o Javascript ativado no navegador quando o usuário desativá-lo em algum momento por algum motivo utilizando a tag `<noscript>E uma mensagem aqui informando para ativar o Javascript</noscript>`.

E para concluir, essa seria a outra maneira de realizar o redirecionamento após autenticação:

`login.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php require_once 'html\head.php' ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function login(){
            var myData = $("#login").serialize();
            arquivo = "valida.php";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                data: myData,
                url: arquivo,
                success:function(response){
                    if(response.autenticado){
                        window.location.href = 'ok.php';
                    }else{
                        $('#ret').html(response.mensagem).show();
                    }
                },
                error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    $('#ret').html(response.mensagem).show();
                }
            });
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="assets/img/truck.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            Teste
        </a>
        <form id="login" class="form-inline">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Usuário" aria-label="User">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="Senha" aria-label="Pass">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-warning my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" onclick="login();">Entrar</button>
        </form>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="ret"></div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

`valida.php`

```
set_time_limit(10);

$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'user');
$pswd = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'pswd');

if (isset($user) && isset($pswd)) {

    if ($user == 'rbz' && $pswd == 123) {
        $response = array('autenticado' => true, 'mensagem' => '');
    }else{
        $response = array('autenticado' => false, 'mensagem' => 'Atenção! Usuário ou senha incorretos');
    }

}else{
    $response = array('autenticado' => true, 'mensagem' => 'Atenção! Usuário ou senha incorretos');
}

return json_encode($response);
```

Este script foi só para exemplificar e guiá-lo sobre como obter sucesso com seu redirecionamento. Claro que você pode melhorar isto e manipular o resultado da sua autenticação de maneira mais livre com o Javascript / jQuery.

Comment: "porque os cabeçalhos de resposta já foram enviados antes" em que momento exatamente do arquivo `valida.php` foram enviados os cabeçalhos antes da função `header`?

Comment: Perdão. Permita-me corrigir, no arquivo citado pelo autor da pergunta, não na minha sugestão. Falta de atenção minha.